Spring boot: Disable autoconfiguration classes
I'm using spring boot along with other spring libraries like spring-data-mongo, actuator, micrometer...
By default, all autoconfiguration classes are enabled.
When I set logger.level.root=DEBUG it tells me that a lot of autoconfiguration classes misses conditions.
Example spring boot debug snippet:
Neo4jRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.neo4j.driver.Driver' (OnClassCondition)

   NewRelicMetricsExportAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.micrometer.newrelic.NewRelicMeterRegistry' (OnClassCondition)

   NoOpMeterRegistryConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry' simpleMeterRegistry (OnBeanCondition)

   NoopTracerAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer' (OnClassCondition)

   OAuth2AuthorizationServerAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2Authorization' (OnClassCondition)

I'd like to activate just AutoConfiguration classes I need and avoid to evaluate AutoConfiguration classes I don't need.
How could I disable autoconfiguration classes and activate just autoconfiguration I need?
Any ideas?

Don't. That is going to be a lot of effort for little to no gain.

You cannot disable all autoconfiguration but @SpringBootApplication has an "exclude" parameter to selectively disable all you don't want.
But as @M.Deinum wrote, it's not worth it. Adding only the necessary dependencies to build.gradle.kts is Spring's way to limit what gets autoloaded.
Also see Disable all Database related auto configuration in Spring Boot
